# Predefined type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1' is not defined or imported

Tags: .net

I'm trying to use a readonly collection in my c# project, but it says it can't find it in System.Collections.Generic. I'm using .Net Framework 4 Client Profile. Am I using the wrong version?

I'm trying to use it in a `LinkedList<int>`

`_history.Sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type was added in .NET Framework 4.5; so it won't exist in 4.0 (client-profile or otherwise). See "applies to" in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to).